# npx create-react-app myapp error "\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\19748" does not contain a package.json file in appdata folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

OS: Windows
for creating react app using npx i've write the following command:

```
npx create-react-app myapp
```

it shows this error:

```
npm ERR! Could not install from "myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\19748" as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: There's threads about this already, e.g.: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4058 Did they not help?

Comment: Dear @Jayce444 i've tried the method described in the answer and it worked for me please check, and on github they are suggesting to install  it globally using npm but I wanna install it using npx

Comment: Which NodeJS version do you use @SarthakBhagwat ?

Comment: @TasosBu v12.18.3

Answer (score 47, accepted):

this error occurs usually when name of the PC contain a space like

```
mycomputer name
```

you should fix this by redefine your npm cache root There is a simple workaround to fix this problem. 8.3 DOS path format should be used. Open command prompt in administration mode then cd to C:\Users and run this command :

```
C:\Users>dir /x
```

and find the short path for your desired directory i.e. username let us say it is MYCOMP~1 (it's not always MYCOMP~1 )
try:

```
npm config set cache "C:\Users\MYCOMP~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache" --global
```

be careful for space character in the pc name you should use the one you got from command prompt instead
and now use:

```
npx create-react-app myapp
```

happy coding!!!

Comment: Works like charm... Thanks for the guidance

Comment: @SarthakBhagwat Really helped me. Thanks!

Comment: What if your name is `Some Body Help` what should i type?

Comment: If you follow the steps closely, they should still work @Khant

Comment: Ahh you absolute hero i was about to just reformat everything and start again ha

Answer (score 11):

I am late for the party but I had the same problem with name space in my PC directory. What I did to fix this problem was to:

1. create empty folder in other location than C like on D directory named folder/npm-cache
2. in terminal I run :
   `npm config set cache "D:\name-cache\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache" --global`
3. If you still want to have it on your current path that has space in username

like "C:\Users\Firstname Lastname\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache"
you can replace the string after space with "~1"

`npm config set cache "C:\Users\Firstname~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache" --global`

This answer was taken from from https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/146.

Answer (score 0):

Hy as they said above this error occurs usually when name of the PC contain a space like
**step 1**: navigate to `C:\Users>` and run `C:\Users>dir /x`
[image]

The **USERPC~1** is an alternative name for **USER PC** on my system. notice the space between **USER** and **PC**

**step 2:** Now run `npm config set cache "C:\Users\USERPC~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache" --global` if you have e.g. **DAM SAM** `use DAMSAM~1`

**step 3:** now run `npm config edit`. it will open a txt file, look for where your cache is and check if the path you ran above matches the one in the txt file
[image]

**step 4**: if it matches save the file and run `npx create-react-app`.it will run. If not change the path manually to `"C:\Users\USERPC~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache"` as was in my case.

**step 5:** ensure you save the .txt file. then run `npx create-react-app` command